# SlimerJs, problems with using CLI

Tags: phantomjs, slimerjs

I want use SlimerJS with proxy, for this was a CLI options.
Example:

```
slimerjs --proxy=192.100.1.1:3129 --proxy-auth=user:pass --proxy-type=socks5 script.js
```

but, raised Exception

```
unknown option: --proxy=192.100.1.1:3129
```

**OS:** Windows 7 Proffesional 64-bit
**SlimerJS:** version 0.9.6.

What i should doing for using CLI options in SlimerJS

**UPD:**
It is bug, will be fixed in last vesrion SlimerJs ( [Issue on a Github](https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/issues/392) )

Comment: What slimerjs version do you have? That option is supported since 0.9 according to the documentation.

Comment: @ArtjomB. SlimerJs version 0.9.6. In my PC even simple command not run "slimerjs -v", but command "slimerjs -help" working